# Crystal Reports groups in multiple columns page breaking after row

Tags: crystal-reports, multiple-columns

I have a crystal report that I formatted to have the groups display in multiple (4) columns across the page, using the Format with Multiple Columns and Format Groups with multiple column options in the section expert.

The data driving the report is (snake draft):

round  pick  team name
=====  ====  ==========
1         1       Charlie
1           2          Bob
1             3          Sam
1             4          Kevin
2             1          Kevin
2             2          Sam
2             3          Bob
2             4          Charlie
3             1          Charlie
3             2          Bob
3             3          Sam
3             4          Kevin
4             1           Kevin
4             2          Sam
4             3          Bob
4             4          Charlie
5             1          Charlie
5             2          Bob
5             3          Sam
5             4          Kevin
6             1          Kevin
6             2          Sam
6             3          Bob
6             4          Charlie

I want the output to look like:

Round 1   Round 2  Round 3   Round 4
1 Charlie  1 Kevin   1 Charlie   1 Kevin
2 Bob       2 Sam     2 Bob        2 Sam
3 Sam      3 Bob      3 Sam       3 Bob
4 Kevin    4 Charlie 4 Kevin     4 Charlie
Round 5   Round 6
1 Charlie  1 Kevin
2 Bob       2 Sam
3 Sam      3 Bob
4 Kevin    4 Charlie

I have 2 problems:

1) I don't need the group footer, but, if I suppress it, the groups don't display in multiple columns across the page, they just go down the page.

2) If I don't suppress the group footer, the first row of columns displays exactly like I want it, but, there is a page break between the rows of columns. So, rounds 5 and 6 appear on the next page. I have verified that all of the 'new page' options are unchecked in the section expert.

I have the "Round #" in the group header and that is showing correctly. One thing that is weird is that if I put a literal in the group footer, it shows at the very bottom of the page below each column. It's as if CR wants to use the entire page for the column height, even though it doesn't need it.

Can anyone help me out?

Thanks,
Dan

Answer (score 1):

Keep the round information in the main report.  Put the # in the details section and format in multiple sections (like you've done).

Move the pick/teammate information to a subreport.  format as desired.  place subreport in a second detials section.  link main to subreport on round.